# Upload image from webform in Python

Tags: python, pylons, python-imaging-library

I am new to python and I am assigned the task of making an image uploade script from a webform in python.  We are using Pylons.
I have a form submitting to a page and am trying to run the follow but I am getting this error

> AttributeError: read

My code is this:

```
im = Image.open(request.POST['image'])  
im = im.convert("RGB")  
im = im.resize((70,70), Image.ANTIALIAS)  
im.save("/avatars/q5.png")
```

Any help is greatly, greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you uploading the Image? Using HTML Form for using Python itself? If using python are you sending the proper `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this:

```
im = Image.open(StringIO(request.POST['image']))
```

since the Image.open function takes a file-like object not a buffer. The [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) packages turns a buffer into a file-like object.

Comment: I did that.  Now I am getting IOError: cannot identify image file.  Does that mean the file is coming throught the form properly?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like it's not being uploaded properly. Check to make sure length(request.POST['image']) is the number of bytes that the file is supposed to be.